# no element "rtpmp2tdepay" . How can i install it

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, rtp

i am a new guy in gstreamer. I am trying to run the following command in my raspberrypi

gst-launch-0.10 -v udpsrc port=1234 caps='application/x-rtp,payload=(int)96,encoding-name=(string)H264' ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! autovideosink sync=True

i am getting following error
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "rtpmp2tdepay"

any idea how can i slove it ? how can install the element "rtpmp2tdepay"

thanks again for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rtpmp2tdepay is included in the [gstreamer good plugin](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-plugin-rtp.html).

in your command line type in :

```
sudo apt-get install gst-plugins-good
```